# How to slide down one DIV behind the other

Tags: jquery, animation

This is my HTML markup:

```
Text Text
Text Text

<div class="main_navi">
    NAVIGATION GOES HERE
</div>
<div class="sub_navi">
    SUBNAVIGATION GOES HERE
</div>
```

I'd like to hide `sub_navi` behind the `main_navi` and when clicking on `main_navi`, the `sub_navi` DIV should slide down.

I'm wondering how to position the `sub_navi` DIV properly in order to slide? Negative top position, maybe?

Thanks.

Comment: I have an answer for you, Fuxi, please check and let me know if it's what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple example of what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.main_navi').click(function() {
       $('.sub_navi').show(1200);
    });
  });​
```

#### [Working Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ZubAb/)

Another example, is a little bit more complicated with a delay, to make it more smooth:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.main_navi').toggle(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.sub_navi').show();
        }, 250);
        $('.sub_navi').animate({
            top: '+=15'
        }, 600);
    }, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.sub_navi').hide();
        }, 200);
        $('.sub_navi').animate({
            top: '-=15'
        }, 500);
    });
});​
```

#### [Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/t9xTS/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/xcBfy/)

```
$('.sub_navi').slideDown();
```

Should get the work done for you..